# Bookmark list of files

Tags: elisp

I want to achieve: function `bookmark-config-files` which takes all the files matching mask "asdasd-*.el" in `$user-emacs-directory/els/` (path for example)

I'm achieving now: list of bookmarks named after files, but are pointing on file and place where I executed `bookmark-config-files` function.

My first approach was to use `bookmark-set-name` and `bookmark-set-filename` on a constructed bookmark object, but `bookmark-make-record` is wrong for that purpose, because creates bookmark at point.

```
(defun bookmark-config-files ()
  (let* (($config-files (directory-files "./" t "^asdasd.*el$")))
    (dolist ($config-file $config-files )
      (bookmark-set-filename (bookmark-make-record) $config-file))))
```

Then I turned to an idea to find files and then use `bookmark-make-record`, then close it, but this function bookmarks current point (where it was evaluated) again, and also such 'find-file' solution far from being efficient.

```
(defun bookmark-config-files ()
  (let* (($config-files (directory-files "./" t "^asdasd.*el$")))
    (dolist ($config-file $config-files)
      (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect $config-file)
        (bookmark-make-record)
        (kill-buffer))
      )))
```

So how can I take set of files from dir and make bookmarks of them?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with each of your attempts? Can you [edit] to clarify what you get and how that differs from what you want? Also, try to think of a better title _(How to set bookmarks in a set of files?_ perhaps?)

Comment: Hi, tried to rearrange it a bit for clarity. In general I would not want to "set bookmarks in a set of files" because find-file is very costly, I would love just to get `bookmark-alist` filled with proper bookmark entries if possible, but don't want to build function which will be making them, I believe there is already such function which I can't find. –